# Java Client for WebRTC or Janus Gateway

Tags: java, webrtc

I'm here asking for some assistance of this community since my Google abilities aren't very top notch lately.

I was looking for a Java Client for Janus Gateway WebRTC Server. I know that could be difficult and based on my searches it is.

So, I need to compromise, if there is no such library as I desired.
I could work if there was a Java Client for WebRTC (low level or high level API client).
So I can use it  and build on top of it to interact with WebRTC server.

But unfortunately I haven't found any proper Java Client for WebRTC as well, just some snippets for Android that I can't fit on my needs.

Any advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open-source desktop library in devopvoid's GitHub repository called [webrtc-java](https://github.com/devopvoid/webrtc-java). It is a JNI implementation to enable development of RTC applications for desktop platforms running Java, so specifically it is not for Android.

The client can be found in the webrtc-demo folder. There, there is a webrtc-demo-api which could be extended to meet the requirements.